# Verify my proof: for two positive natural numbers $x$,$y$ , if $ x + y = 2$ , then $ x = y = 1 $

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Could someone verify my proof and my proof-writing?

**Proposition**:  for two positive natural numbers  $x$,$y$ , if $ x + y = 2$ , then $ x = y = 1 $ 
**Proof**: Suppose $ y $ is any positive natural number. By the definition of order, $ x + y = 2 \Leftrightarrow x < 2 $. The only positive natural number lesser than 2 is 1. So if $ x+ y =2 $, then $ x = 1 $. 
Analogically we can proof $ y = 1 $. 
It follows if $ x + y = 2 $ , then $ x = y = 1 $. 
Q.E.D.

Comment: I think proving the contrapositive also works here.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, I think the proof by contrapositive is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that $ x + y = 2 \Leftrightarrow x < 2 $. The $\Rightarrow$ really holds, but $\Leftarrow$ doesn't really holds. What holds is that $x<2\Rightarrow\exists z(\ \neq 0 \, \wedge \, x+z=2)$. Well, you just need the $\Rightarrow$ implication to complete your argument, so you may just swap the $\Leftrightarrow$ symbol by the $\Rightarrow$ symbol.

Last thing: As you said, the only positive natural number lesser than $2$ is $1$. Have you proven it? If you have, then it's okay.

Comment: 2 is the successor of the successor of 0, the only element who has no successor (  for any $ n \in \mathbb{N}$, $ s(n) = 0 $ is false ). $ 2 = s(s(0)) $. 0 is not positive. $s(s(0))$ is the successor of $s(0)$, so $ s(0) $ is the only positive number lesser than $ s(s(0))$, by definition. Is that correct?